# if statement or unexpected nil while unwrapping error; unsure of which

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, textbox, option-type

*Quick note, the picture will help explain my situation.  So at the moment, I just add the Cum. credits and GPA text fields to my GPA calculator app.  These two fields are optional, while the other 4 fields underneath are not.  Here is the majority of my code (please excuse the redundancy for the moment).

```
         if CumCredits == "" || CumGPA == ""
        {
            let credit1 = Float(Credits1TF.text!)!
            let credit2 = Float(Credits2TF.text!)!

            let grade1 = Float(Grade1TF.text!)!
            let grade2 = Float(Grade2TF.text!)!

            let firstgrade = credit1 * grade1
            let secondgrade = credit2 * grade2

            let allcredits = credit1 + credit2
            let allgrades = firstgrade + secondgrade

            let finalgrade = round((allgrades / allcredits) * 10000)/10000


            GPALabel.text = "Your Semester GPA is: \(finalgrade)"
            GPALabel.hidden = false

            Class1TF.resignFirstResponder()
            Class2TF.resignFirstResponder()
            Credits1TF.resignFirstResponder()
            Credits2TF.resignFirstResponder()
            Grade1TF.resignFirstResponder()
            Grade2TF.resignFirstResponder()


            }
            else {
            let credit1 = Float(Credits1TF.text!)!
            let credit2 = Float(Credits2TF.text!)!

            let grade1 = Float(Grade1TF.text!)!
            let grade2 = Float(Grade2TF.text!)!

            let firstgrade = credit1 * grade1
            let secondgrade = credit2 * grade2

            let allcredits = credit1 + credit2
            let allgrades = firstgrade + secondgrade

            let finalgrade = round((allgrades / allcredits) * 10000)/10000

            Class1TF.resignFirstResponder()
            Class2TF.resignFirstResponder()
            Credits1TF.resignFirstResponder()
            Credits2TF.resignFirstResponder()
            Grade1TF.resignFirstResponder()
            Grade2TF.resignFirstResponder()
            CumCredits.resignFirstResponder()
            CumGPA.resignFirstResponder()

            let CCredits = Float(CumCredits.text!)!
            let CGPA = Float(CumGPA.text!)!

            //top math
            let LastGrade = CCredits * CGPA
            let MegaCredits = allcredits + CCredits
            let MegaGPA = allgrades + LastGrade
            let MegaEverything = (round((MegaGPA / MegaCredits) * 10000)/10000) - 0.0001

            CumTotal.hidden = false
            CumTotal.text = "Your expected cumulative GPA is: \(MegaEverything)"
            GPALabel.text = "Your Semester GPA is: \(finalgrade)"
            GPALabel.hidden = false

            Class1TF.resignFirstResponder()
            Class2TF.resignFirstResponder()
            Credits1TF.resignFirstResponder()
            Credits2TF.resignFirstResponder()
            Grade1TF.resignFirstResponder()
            Grade2TF.resignFirstResponder()
            CumCredits.resignFirstResponder()
            CumGPA.resignFirstResponder()

        }
```

At the moment (and to my knowledge), if the Cum. Credits and GPA are left alone, the top portion of my statement executes, and if they are not empty, the else statement executes.

So my problem... If I enter a value for each field, everything words and I have no problem.  However, if I leave either the Cum. Credits or GPA field empty, my program crashes and I get the typical "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" dealing with either

```
 let CCredits = Float(CumCredits.text!)!
 let CGPA = Float(CumGPA.text!)!
```

I've tried a number of possible solution: re-writing code and re-wording code and I can't seem to get it.  What would you be able to suggest?

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens when trying to force-unwrap an optional, so first look at each of the "!" used and you will likely find one of them is nil.

*edit*
After looking over and talking in the comments, it seems your if statement should be

```
!CumCredits.characters.isEmpty || !CumGPA.characters.isEmpty
```

What's likely happening in this case is the values in your fields are empty strings, so trying to create a float from an entry string will result in a nil value.

One solution would be putting a guard statement at the top of the function so the error causing code is never run:

```
guard let credits1Text = Credits1TF.text, 
          credits2Text = Credits2TF.text, 
          grade1Text = Grade1TF.text, 
          grade2Text = Grad2TF.text
where !credits1Text.characters.isEmpty && !credits2Text.characters.isEmpty 
     && !grade1Text.characters.isEmpty && !grade2Text.characters.isEmpty else {
   *handle case where float conversion won't work*
}
*continue on with normal code, using verified values created in guard*
```

Comment: your last statement... intrigues me.  At first I was going to agree, but then I stopped myself.  At the moment, the first portion of my code runs over that float/nil dilemma if either are empty/nil.  As simply as it may be, are my if statement proper?

Comment: It will likely be CumCredits.text or CumGPA.text that is nil. To see for sure, find the string on one line and then convert it to a float on the next line

Comment: yes, haha.  Is that proper code?  it seems like that would work well?  However, i'm still learning.  However, could I use that piece of code the other way, if CC == "" || CG == ""?

Comment: I think the proper way is !stringName.characters.isEmpty, but it should work either way

Comment: Added the fix to the answer

Comment: PEEJWEEJ, thank you very much for entertaining my question.  With your help, I was able to talk/work myself through to the eventual answer.  Thank you for your time, Jon.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the if - statement.

```
I should have had CumCredits.text == "" || CumGPA.text == ""
```

That way, if my text fields are empty, they pass over the first portion of my code.